# Jquery modal dialog on all hyperlink clicks in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I have a page where I need to show a modal dialog on the click of all the hyperlinks.

The popup has two buttons Images "Continue" and "GoBack". I wrote some jquery which I found on this Stackoverflow website. But there is a problem with code.

Suppose I have 5 hyperlinks in this page. When I  click on the first link its opening the dialog and when I click on continue its opening the link properly.

But when I click on the second link its opening again the first link and the second link 
two separate windows, Which is wrong it supposed to open only second link.

When I click on the third link again its opening first,second and third links in 3 windows.

I guess I am doing a small mistake in my code. If anyone help me fixing this I really appreciate.

Thanks for your help in advance. Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Loading Modal Dialog Popup-->
$(document).ready(function() {
    //  $(".leaving-the-site-container").hide(); 
    $(".linkdialog").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();                            
        var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");                     
        alert(targetUrl);

        $(".leaving-the-site-container").dialog({        
            width:452,
            // autoOpen:false,
            // height:225,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:false,
            draggable:false,
            scrollbars:false,
            position: ["center", 240]
        });                                                      

        $("#btnContinue").click(function(){                            
            window.open(targetUrl);
            $(".leaving-the-site-container").dialog("close");                                                                         
        }); 
        $("#btnTakeMeBack").click(function(){
            $(".leaving-the-site-container").dialog("close");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you should format your jquery code so its readable, and also post your html + css, so we know whats going on. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ for this.

Comment: Its formatted code only. I dont understand why its showing like this. Is there any way can I attach the file

Comment: @Henry - I fixed it. The { } button on the edit dialog allows you to format code blocks so that it is easier to read. Simple select the code text and click the { } button.

Comment: @Henry - No problem. When you're formatting code (in general, not just here), consider the spacing/indention you use. I like four consecutive spaces before each indention. Some prefer tabs (I hate them). However, consider how much easier the code is to read after I reformatted the indention of the code itself. This helps with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is incorrect. This'll work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".linkdialog").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.linkdialog').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');                            
    $('.leaving-the-site-container').dialog('open');
});

$(".leaving-the-site-container").dialog({        
    width:452,
    modal:true,
    closeOnEscape:false,
    draggable:false,
    scrollbars:false,
    position: ["center", 240],
        open: function() {
    $("#btnContinue").click(function(){                            
        window.open($('.selected').attr('href'));                                     
        $(".leaving-the-site-container").dialog("close");                                                                         
        }); 
            $("#btnTakeMeBack").click(function(){
        $(".leaving-the-site-container").dialog("close");
    });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Hi rsplak, Your solution is not working. Its the same problem in a different way. Now first click giving null error. second link click opening the same link in two windows. Third lick opening same link in 3 windows and so on. I appreciate your time. any fix for this.

Comment: Any body can help me fix this issue. Its very urgent for me.